# Python and text manipulation

Tags: python, text

I want to learn a text manipulation language and I have zeroed in on Python. Apart from text manipulation Python is also used for numerical applications, machine learning, AI, etc.

My question is how do I approach the learning of Python language so that I am quickly able to write sophisticated text manipulation utilities. Apart from regular expressions in the context of "text manipulation" what language features are more important than others what modules are useful and so on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Beyond regular expressions here are some important features:

- Generators, see [Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/) by David Beazley for a lot of great examples to pipeline unlimited amounts of text through generators.

For tools, I recommend looking at the following:

- [Whoosh](http://whoosh.ca/), a pure Python search engine that will give you some nice real life examples of parsing text using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) and text processing in Python in general.
- Ned Batcheldor's nice [reviews of various Python parsing tools](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html).
- [mxTextTools](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxTextTools/)
- [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/) source code for more advanced text processing in Python, including a sophisticated state machine.

**Edit:** A good links specific to text processing in Python:

- [Text Processing in Python](http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/) by David Mertz.  I think the book is still available, although it's probably a bit dated now.

Answer (score 4):

There's a book [Text Processing in Python](http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/). I didn't read it myself yet but I've read other articles of this author and generally they're a good staff.

Answer (score 2):

I found the object.__doc__ and dir(obj) commands incredibly useful in learning the language.

e.g.

```
a = "test,test,test"
```

What can I do with a?  dir(a).  Seems I can split a.

```
vec = a.split (",")
```

What is vec?  vec.__doc__:

"new list initialized from sequence's items"

What can I do with vec? dir(vec).

```
vec.sort ()
```

etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't read, [Python for Data Analysis by Wes McKinney - 1 edition (October 8, 2012)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009NLMB8Q) looks promising.